# Firestore make function trigger once opening the App, then after changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want this function to trigger once I start the App, then every time there is a change in my firestore data.

```
export const getDuettsPlayer1 = (setDuetts) => {
  duettsRef.where("player1", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      setDuetts(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

I already tried it like this:

```
const getDuettsPlayer1 = (setDuetts) => {
  duettsRef.where("player1", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      setDuetts(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}
```

, but then i got
`TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...}).catch(function (error) {...')`
How do i do this correctly?

Comment: Can you show the precise code that throws that error?

Comment: I added the code, which throws that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onSnapshot` doesn't return a promise, so it doesn't have a `catch` method.

Instead you handle errors by passing in a second listener:

```
  duettsRef.where("player1", "==", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      setDuetts(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    }, (error) => {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

Also see the Firestore documentation on [listening for errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#handle_listen_errors)